# Store string in array at position mentioned in string

Tags: c++

I have a string messages read in from a file in the format:

```
{<1>}Hello!

{<2>}What is up!
How is everyone?

{<5>}Things are great here!

{<4>}{[Cameron]}Are things good?
```

I need to create a string array and store each individual message in the position specified between the `"{< >}" without the "{< >}"` and `"{[username]}."` I can get the value of the integer in the section of the string using:

```
int time = 5;
string messages = "{<1>}Hello!\n\n{<2>}What is up!\nHow is everyone?\n\n\{<5>}Things are great here!\n\n{<4>}{[Cameron]}Are things good?\n";

string temp;
string timestamp;
int position;

int start = -1;
int end;
int next = 0; 

while(next != -1)
{
   start = messages.find("{<",start+1);
   end = messages.find(">}",start+1);
   next = messages.find("{<",start+1);

   timestamp = messages.substr(start+2,end-start-2);

   if(next == -1)
      temp = messages.substr(end+2,messages.length()-end-2);
   else
      temp = messages.substr(end+2,next-end-2);

   position = std::stoi(timestamp);

   \\This is where I would add temp to position timestamp of an array of strings.
}
```

This string number would have to be converted to an integer so I can use it to specify the row the string will be stored in. I have found that I should be able to use `stoi() to convert strings to integers`, but I get **error** `"'stoi' is not a member of 'std'."`

Aside from this error, how would I go about adding the strings temp to a string array at position position respectively? The variable time would be the number of messages that could be added to the array.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. For `std::stoi` you need to add the following at the top of your file

   ```
   #include <string>
   ```

   and you need to tell your compiler to use C++11 standard e.g. if using g++ pass to the compiler argument `-std=c++11`
2. To add a string to an array of strings, first make sure the array is big enough. E.g. if you know you will have 10 strings then define

   ```
   std::array<std::string, 10> str_array;
   ```

   (make sure you have : `#include <array>`)

   Then if you want to insert `temp` at position `position`

   ```
   str_array[position] = temp;
   ```
3. If you don't know the size beforehand and **positions are in ascending order** in the file, you may want to use a `std::vector`. E.g.
   At the top

   ```
   #include <vector>
   ```

   outside the loop define

   ```
   std::vector<std::string> strings;
   ```

   and in the loop

   ```
   strings.emplace_back(temp);
   ```
4. If positions/timestamps are in random order in the file or if the array may be sparse you could use a map. E.g.
   At the top

   ```
   #include <map>
   ```

   outside the loop define

   ```
   std::map<int, std::string> strings;
   ```

   and in the loop

   ```
   strings.emplace(position, temp);
   ```

Comment: I have included <string> as suggested. I get the same error of "'array' is not a member of 'std'" when I try to create an array. The commands I use to compile and run are: "g++ insertTest.cpp -o insert.out" followed by "./insert.out" which gives me error mentioned above. I tried "g++ -std=c++11 insertTest.cpp -o insert.out" and received the same errors.

Comment: What version of gcc are you using ? To use `array` you need to `#include <array>`

Comment: Im using gcc version 4.8.4 I believe.

Comment: you can find out with `gcc -v`, Such a recent version of gcc should definitely support C++11 and `stoi`

Comment: I found the issue. Stoi() now works and compiles. Is there no way to create the string array of size variable time? Otherwise I will just have to preallocate the array size to 1,000,000 and hope there is never that many messages to be added.

Comment: Every time I hoped for the best in software development I got disappointed :-(

Comment: You are THE BEST Manos. I will likely use map instead of array as the preallocation angers me. Thank you very much for the help.

Comment: One last thing. I do think you meant to use emplace rather than emplace_back in your fourth solution involving map.

Comment: Wanted to see if you were paying attention ;-)